# MVVM. Xamarin. Does it not change the value of the text (LabelText)? Why?

Tags: xamarin.forms, mvvm, binding

xaml:
Codigo xaml


<ContentPage.BindingContext>
local:ClockRegisterViewModel/
</ContentPage.BindingContext>

```
            <Label Text="Enter your ID: " FontSize="21" TextColor="Red" />
            <Entry x:Name="imputEntry"
                   Text="{Binding GetInputValue}"
                   FontSize="Large" Placeholder="Enter your ID" 
                   ReturnCommand="{Binding AddTodoCommand}"
            />
            <Label Text="{Binding LabelText}" FontSize="21" TextColor="Blue"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage>
```

MVVM Codigo:
namespace StudentLoginApp
{
public class ClockRegisterViewModel
{
public ObservableCollection ListStudents { get; set; }

```
    public ClockRegisterViewModel()
    {
        ListStudents = new ObservableCollection<ListStudent>();
        ListStudents.Add(new ListStudent("01", "Dante"));
        ListStudents.Add(new ListStudent("02", "Efrain"));
        ListStudents.Add(new ListStudent("03", "Bryan"));
        ListStudents.Add(new ListStudent("04", "Adams"));
        ListStudents.Add(new ListStudent("05", "Nick"));
    }
    public ICommand AddTodoCommand => new Command(CheckId);
    public string GetInputValue { get; set; }
    public string LabelText { get; set; }

    public void CheckId()
    {
        this.LabelText = "test";

        var sd = ListStudents.Where(x => x.IdStudent == GetInputValue);
        if (!sd.Any())
        {
            UserDialogs.Instance.Alert(new AlertConfig
            {
                Message = "ID incorrect",
                OkText = "OK",
                Title = "Validation Check In"
            });
            return;
        }
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you viewmodel, when the value changes, it will not notify the UI to update.You need to make your viewmodel implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Such as:

```
public class ClockRegisterViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
```

And then you need a event to notify the UI when the value is changed in you viewmodel.

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

In addition, when you set the value, you need to call the event `PropertyChanged`. Such as

```
string labelText;
public string LabelText
    {
        set
        {
            if (labelText != value)
            {
                labelText = value;
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("LabelText"));
                }
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return labelText;
        }
    }
```

Finally, bind the labelText in the xaml.

```
<Label Text="{Binding labelText}" FontSize="21" TextColor="Blue"/>
```

If you need more information, you can check the official document:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm